# Expected unqualified-id before numeric constant. - Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

This is my first time on here, I'm rather new to C++, need help with my code. It says that I'm missing a _ after a _, but I can't find anything wrong.

```
void loop() {

 digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW); 
 delayMicroseconds(2); 

 digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
 delayMicroseconds(10); 

 digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
 duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
 Serial.println(distance);

 distance = duration/58.2;

 if (distance < 50){
Serial.print("50");
 digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
 digitalWrite(LED3. LOW); 
 }
 else if (distance < 150){ 
 Serial.print("150");
 digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
 digitalWrite(LED2, HIGH);
 digitalWrite(LED3. LOW); 
 }
 else if (distance < 99999){ 
 Serial.print("INF");
 digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
 digitalWrite(LED2, LOW);
 digitalWrite(LED3. HIGH); 
 }

}
```

If you guys/gals can help, that would be apprecited.

Cheers.

Comment: Look at the lines with the error and compare them to the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several places where you use a period instead of a comma.

```
digitalWrite(LED3. LOW); 
//               ^
```

Should be

```
digitalWrite(LED3, LOW); 
//               ^
```

Comment: Your name fits well with this observation.  :-)  Or maybe the opposite of your name (Captain Obvious).  Or maybe both.  ;-)